# Discord bot discord.py commands aren't working

Tags: python, command, discord.py

I'm fairly new to making discord bots, and I'm trying to make a basic test command, where you say (prefix)test abc, and the bot says abc too. I get no errors, but when I type r!test abc, nothing happens. I get nothing in the terminal, either.

Here is my code.

```
import discord

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()


GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD') # Same thing but gets the server name
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='r!')
TOKEN = 'TOKENGOESHERE'
on = "I'm up and running!"
print("Booting up...")
channel = client.get_channel(703869904264101969)

@client.event # idk what this means but you have to do it

async def on_ready(): # when the bot is ready

    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord! They have connected to the following server: ' #client.user is just the bot name
    f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})' # guild.name is just the server name


    )

    channel2 = client.get_channel(channelidishere)
    await channel2.send(on)
#everything works up until I get to here, when I run the command, nothing happens, not even some output in the terminal.

@commands.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")



client.run(TOKEN)
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The bot doesn't respond, that's the problem. I have tried many other commands, where the bot creates a channel, or gives someone a role, but these don't work either. Even basic commands, where it prints something in the terminal, don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue is that you are not defining your decorators correctly. Since you are using commands you only need the `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='r!')` statement. The `client = discord.Client()` is not needed. Since it is `bot = ...`, all your decorators need to start with `@bot`. Also, your won't use client , you'll use bot like `channel2 = bot.get_channel(channelidishere)`.

Removed the guild loop and replaced it with [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) to get the guild - `guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name=GUILD)`. This requires another import - `import discord`

Try this:

```py
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')  # Same thing but gets the server name
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='r!')
on = "I'm up and running!"
print("Booting up...")


@bot.event  # idk what this means but you have to do it
async def on_ready():  # when the bot is ready
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name=GUILD)
    print(
        f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord! They have connected to the following server: '  # client.user is just the bot name
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})')  # guild.name is just the server name
    channel2 = bot.get_channel(channelidishere)
    await channel2.send(on)


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```